# Conditional logistic regression or GEE in PS matched study

Tags: regression, generalized-estimating-equations, matching, propensity-scores, clogit

#### My situation:

> In a cohort study, I'm trying to find the correlation between outcome & Tx (Arm A vs Arm B). However, baseline covariates are unbalance between different treatment groups. Hence, I use propensity score to balancing the covariates , and create a 1:2 matched data set.

#### My questions :

> Q(A): 
>     After PS method with 1:2 matching, if the covariates are binary , should I use conditional logistic regression method or GEE to check if there are significant covariates difference between Tx groups ?

#### Information I know    :

> Conditional logistic regression applies fixed effects and given the subject specific estimate but GEE gives the population average estimates.

for example

> In a model:  Covariate(DM=1) =  *B* * Tx  ;
>
> > If using conditional logistic regression , 
> >     the result e^*B* would imply the odds ratio of Tx-A vs Tx-B to DM=1 if Tx-B is  reference group.    P value of the Tx parameter would give conclusion if the 2 different tx groups are statistical significantly different.  The *B* is also the subject specific estimate;
>
> Q(B):
>
> If the above is correct, then I'm quite confused about whats is the population average estimate in the model in GEE ?

Thanks a lot for any hint or help ~